# Create a macro that is executed when a cel value chages (not by the user)

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

Ok I have a worksheet "Goal 0" that with some ranges, make some calculations like...

(in A1)

```
=SUM(G2:G68)*I17
```

Then if I add/modify any of the values in 62-G68, the cell is auto calculated (numbers that are mainly negative and some possitive).

The objetive is: According to the sum of the range, find the value of I17 where the result of A1 is equal or more than 0. (Starting from 0, incrementing it 1 by 1, decimals not needed)

Manually I can add change i17 untill it reaches the goal. How ever I want to make it automatically, so if a value in the range of G2 to G68 changes it recalculate the value of I17, untill (A1 calculation gets value equal or higher than 0) but if already is higger or equal than 0 then do nothing.

Hope I explain it well

**EDIT:** Now I created this code ...

```
Function IncreaseTheValue()
    If Range("A1") < 0 Then
        Range("I17").Value = 0

        Do While Range("A1").Value < 0
            Range("I17").Value = Range("I17").Value + 1
        Loop
    End If
End Function
```

And works perfect, how ever it does not fires when I make a chage. How do I do that...

I try adding this in A2 cell but did not worked ...

```
=IF(A1 < 0, IncreaseTheValue(), "")
```

Regards

Comment: Sorry I forgot that, no I17 must be alway a number equal or higher than 0, the starting point is 0.

Comment: Following the suggestion of "pnuts" I find this video (skip to minute 2:10+): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YAugMpW-aJw  using solver does not work for this, because it needs to be executed manually everitime I need to recalculate the value of I17, so I edited the question to add more data and request it as a macro or function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't really be doing this as a `Function`; it is inadequate as you notice, but also not appropriate use of a `Function` where a `Sub` or event handler is more appropriate.

Based on your requirements, put the code in the `Worksheet_Change` event handler. You will need to fine-tune it so that it only fires when a change is made in the range `G2:G68`.

Try this (untested):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G2:G68")) Is Nothing Then
    If Range("A1") < 0 Then
        Range("I17").Value = 0
        Do While Range("A1").Value < 0
            Range("I17").Value = Range("I17").Value + 1
        Loop
    End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

**Updated** per pnuts comments. This method below will trigger the macro any time any cell changes -- this might be overkill, or it might be necessary if G2:G68 is formulas which change based on changes to *other* cells.  Either method can be fine-tuned to better suit your exact needs.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Range("A1") < 0 Then
        Range("I17").Value = 0
        Do While Range("A1").Value < 0
            Range("I17").Value = Range("I17").Value + 1
        Loop
    End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes this did the trick, opnuts. Not always gives 0! as David noticed and (i forgot to say) most of the values of the cells are calculations that are made on other cells. How ever this "formula" is to calculate "how many products (I17) are needed to be sold to get a possitive income" as lower the number of I17 the higger the loss of for the sale of the products. So the values of G2:G68 are ALL the variables implicated on creating that product, so if the price of one of the component is increased or decreased the manufacturing price and the products necesary to sold is changed.

Thanks